# Update tableau datasource connection for all worksheets SQL

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

For a bit of background, I have built a series of visualisations (110 worksheets in a single workbook) on Tableau on a local machine. The workbook connects to a local SQL server database which acts as the data source. Each of the 110 visualisations is linked to a unique table within the SQL database (We also use windows authentication to connect to SQL).

We are now migrating the dashboard to a client environment and connecting to their SQL which uses a SQL server authentication. The client SQL database and tables have the exact same name as the one on our local SQL server. The client also has tableau desktop v19.2 installed.

Currently the clients Tableau Desktop requires me to sign in for each worksheet data source to update it, this means I have to sign in 110 times (with each sign in taking around 3-5 minutes). I wanted to ask if there is a way to only sign in once to connect to the database and update all data source connections to point to the new database connection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you already try to open your .twb file with a text editor in order to change the connection and set your new destination?

Comment: If you used Tableau Server, you could embed all the database connection authentication details in the workbook *and* you could swap data sources from local to server simply just one time to ensure they work for every user later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I havent tried using a text editor, will give that a go. I manually updated each data source to get the file working.

Comment: @FabioFantoni cheers, your method worked as a quick solution to update the connections. I will mark this question as closed.